# Why my integer number assignment is invalid?

Tags: c#

This is my test code,it's very simple:

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int number = 0;
            int newNumber = number++;
            Console.WriteLine("the old number is {0},the new number is:{1}", number, newNumber);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

whereas the output result is:'the old number is 1,the new number is:0',I think it's opposite with the result I want.

Comment: It just so happens Microsoft writes documentation about its language features. Before asking a question, make sure you have taken the time to read the documentation, it will make your jedi programming journey a lot smoother https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#increment-operator-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using the postfix increment `++` operator, it first returns the original value, then increments. To get what you want use the prefix increment operator like

```
 int newNumber = ++number;
```

But if you don't want to change `number`, don't use an incrementing operator, use addition/subtraction instead.

Answer (score 2):

That is because `number++` updates the value of number by incrementing it (**[PostFix](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/39463/c-postfix)**). This is done after using the original value in the expression it is used. To achieve the desired behaviour, You can use:

```
int number = 0;
int newNumber = number + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, you have used **number++** which is Post increment operator.
It assigns the value first and then increments its value.
You can achieve your desired output in two ways :

1. Use Pre increment operator

   int newNumber = ++number;
2. Simply adding 1 to number variable and then assigning it to newNumber

   int newNumber = number + 1;